# JQuery show()/hide() selector for start date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

[Here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/chrisfrisina/xBKCR/) is the fiddle.  I am trying to allow the user to select a range (multiple times if they choose) and it show the positions within the time frame.   I can not get the start date input range to work more than once, despite it being on change.  The start date selector code is this:

```
//start selector functionality
    $('#startdate').on('change', function () {
        var $formelem = $(this);
        // Hide all positions that end before the specified date.
        $('section.position time.start').each(function () {
            if (compareTime($(this).attr('datetime'), $formelem.val()) <= 0) {
                $(this).parent().hide();
            } else {
                $(this).parent().show();
            }
        });
        $('section.company > time').remove();
        $('section.company').each(processCompanyTime);
    });
```

Any clues as to why it won't work more than once?   the end selector works multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your `processCompanyTime` function which has a condition to hide the `section.company` but not to show it. So when it's hidden, it will never be shown again.

Comment: from:
if (start.length == 0 && end.length == 0) {
    $(this).hide();
   }
to:
if (start.length == 0 && end.length == 0) {
    $(this).hide();
   } else {
    $(this).show();
   }

THANKS!